# Clang Diagnostics, how to ignore compiler specific extensions

Tags: c++, clang++, llvm-clang

My production code is compiled on a proprietary compiler with some language extensions, for example:

```
__even_in_range(TA2IV, TA2IV_TAIFG);
```

But I am using clang as code analysis tool, and getting this error `error: use of undeclared identifier '__even_in_range'`.  There are few more language extensions that produce similar behavior.  Is there any way to ask clang to ignore certain identifiers?

EDIT:
Both of the comments guided me towards define solution, so I added these compiler options to the code analysis package ( I use https://github.com/lvzixun/Clang-Complete package).

1. `-D __even_in_range(y,x)=y`
2. `-D __interrupt=`

This way none of my sources are influenced by the static analysis tool

Thanks...

Comment: You could add a fake header, #defining these extension without expanding to anything (#define __even_in_range(x,y)). You don't even need to modify the original source, you can specify this header on the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945473/include-one-header-file-in-each-source-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the predefined macro `__clang_analyzer__` to identify that the analyzer is being run, and just `#define` out those extensions in that case:

```
#ifdef __clang_analyzer__
#define __even_in_range(...)
...
#endif
```

Details [here](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html#exclude_code), along with other ideas to get rid of false positives.