# Specify explicit header files in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I have precompiled header file stdafx.h which is specific to each target. My CMake project roughly looks like below:

```
include_directories(<prefix>/include_a)
include_directories(<prefix>/include_b)  #<---- contains stdafx.h that should NOT be used
include_directories(<project_dir>/)  #<----- contains stdafx.h that should be used

add_executable(<project_name> <sources>)
```

Problem: I want to exclude precompiled header that comes as part of `<prefix>/include_b` directory. If thats not possible then specify header files explicitly. I know `gcc` supports `-include` option but is there any cleaner option with CMake that fits my requirement?

Comment: If you don't want to force an include file (which is not explicitly supported by CMake; see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773283/cmake-include-header-into-every-source-file)), I think the answer lays in the order of your include paths. An example for this in hidden in the ["CMake Build System: Transitive Usage Requirements" documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements): see "For example, if the linked libraries for a target must be specified in the order lib1 lib2 lib3 , but the include directories ...".

Comment: `stdafx.h` smells like Visual Studio, but you didn't put a msvc tag?

Comment: @Florian forgot to update this, yes in-fact thats what I ended up doing changing the order.

Comment: @JohanBoule yes because I'm cross compiling for other platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

If you don't want to force an include file (which is not explicitly supported by CMake), I think the answer lays in the order of your include paths.

First here is the test code I used to reproduce your problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(IncDirOrder)

file(WRITE "prefix/include_a/stdafx.h" "#error include_a/stdafx.h")
file(WRITE "prefix/include_b/stdafx.h" "#error include_b/stdafx.h")
file(WRITE "include/stdafx.h" "")
file(WRITE "main.cpp" "#include \"stdafx.h\"\nint main() { return 0; }")

include_directories(prefix/include_a)
include_directories(prefix/include_b)  
include_directories(include)  

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

**Possible Solutions to Influence the Order of Include Paths**

1. Reorder the `include_directories()` calls (if possible):

   ```
   include_directories(include)  
   include_directories(prefix/include_a)
   include_directories(prefix/include_b)
   ```
2. The use of the `BEFORE` keyword:

   ```
   include_directories(BEFORE include)
   ```

   or

   ```
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} BEFORE PUBLIC include)
   ```
3. Going by the assumption that the other pre-compiled headers are also accompanied by a library, I would generally recommend the use of `target_include_directories()`. Then you automatically have the desired behavior (local includes do come first before interface includes):

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
   project(IncDirOrderWithLibs)

   file(WRITE "prefix/source_a/stdafx.cpp" "#define LibA\n#include \"stdafx.h\"")
   file(WRITE "prefix/include_a/stdafx.h" "#ifndef LibA\n#error include_a/stdafx.h\n#endif")
   file(WRITE "prefix/source_b/stdafx.cpp" "#define LibB\n#include \"stdafx.h\"")
   file(WRITE "prefix/include_b/stdafx.h" "#ifndef LibB\n#error include_b/stdafx.h\n#endif")
   file(WRITE "include/stdafx.h" "")
   file(WRITE "main.cpp" "#include \"stdafx.h\"\nint main() { return 0; }")

   add_library(LibA "prefix/source_a/stdafx.cpp")
   target_include_directories(LibA PUBLIC prefix/include_a)

   add_library(LibB "prefix/source_b/stdafx.cpp")
   target_link_libraries(LibB LibA)
   target_include_directories(LibB PUBLIC prefix/include_b)

   add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} LibB)
   target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE include)
   ```

**References**

- [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive)
- [CMake Build System: Transitive Usage Requirements](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements)

Comment: downvoted, totally don't get what's your point and anything to do with ops question