# How to make a custom header available system-wide with clang++?

Tags: c++, header-files, clang++

##### EDIT

**I have been educated about this topic and I have decided to close this question**

*P.S In the comments, can someone tell me how to close my question?*

---

I have some simple C++ code here that I want to compile. I am currently on a mac with MacOS Big Sur running on my computer and I don't have the `<bits/stdc++.h>` file as a "default" header available for all `cpp` files. In order to add it I went in my `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1` folder and made a `bits` folder with a `stdc++.h` file manually. However if I try to compile source code with this header included I get the following error:

```bash
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'bits/stdc++.h' file not found
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Here is my clang version as well:

```bash
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

##### What I want to achieve

1. To compile the code successfully with my manually created `bits/stdc++.h` file. Preferably using `clang++`.
2. (If possible) Find a way to quickly do it.

##### What I've already tried

1. I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945473/include-one-header-file-in-each-source-file) thread with similar question asked, but it the answers provided didn't work for me.
2. I also Linking custom header files when compiling c++, but it seems irrelevant to my problem.

##### My source code

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "Meow Meow Meow\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better to avoid `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h.

Comment: You are playing with internal compiler / library implementation details (like putting custom files into internal directories). And even if we would tell you how to put `<bits/stdc++h>` where the compiler would find it, *it would not do what you think it does*. Also, what wohlstad said -- programs that `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` are basically broken code.

Comment: I know that, but I am a beginner programmer and I just want to use it for the sake of educational purposes. (My teacher also told me to do it too.) It's also less time wasted on reading and memorising different headers. I don't really do big projects. I usually just do some fun programming on https://orac2.info. and <bits/stdc++.h> just gives me more time to use on programming.

Comment: The educational thing to take away here is **don't do it**. And if your teacher tells you to, stand up and educate him. Or find a better teacher. `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not for inclusion by user code, and a terrible habit to get into.

Comment: Thanks everyone for educating me about this <bits/stdc++.h> problem. I really never knew about the downsides,

Comment: If you have a small project it should be even easier. You usually don't need more than a few #includes. Finding which header is required for which class is something you will benefit from. A good source is: https://en.cppreference.com/w/.

Comment: Thanks everyone so much. I was just wondering, what do I do with the question now? do I delete it or edit it or something? I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: As "why this isn't a good idea" was the answer that helped you, even though not being the answer you were looking for, I took the liberty of closing the Q as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - [it's greatly discouraged to use headers like `stdc++.h`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

If you anyway want to do that, you need to find the system directories your version of `clang` looks at. Run the following commands in the terminal:

```
% touch file.cpp
% clang++ -c file.cpp -v
```

At the bottom it should give you output like this:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include
 ...
```

Just chose a directory you think is more suitable for you custom header and add whatever you want to be available for inclusion:

```
% cd /usr/local/include
% sudo mkdir bits && cd bits
% sudo touch stdc++.h
```

Now an include directive of form `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` should work with any cpp file compiled with clang. You only need to populate it with content.